# same function name with different number of params override my base function

Tags: c++

lets say I have a base class B and 2 classes that derived from it:

```
class B
{
public:
     A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf = 0);
}

class D1 : public B {}

class D2 : public B
{
    A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf, U32* faults);
}
```

now, when I call:

```
D1 d1;
d1.Check_Memory(leaf);
```

it call the function from the base class as expected,

but when I do the same with:

```
D2 d2;
d2.Check_Memory(leaf);
```

instead of calling the function from the base class, I get the following error:
function does not take 1 arguments.

does my only solution is declaring another function in D2 that call the base function? is there more elegant way in C++ for doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `D2::Check_Memory` **hides** `B::Check_Memory`.

When you call the function, compiler find where the function is at first, *after that*, it tries to call the function, and if the number of proper function is not 1, it starts to resolve function overloading.

When compiler compiles `d2.Check_Memory(leaf);`, it tries to find what `Check_Memory` is at first. It's easy - `d2` is `class D2`, and it has `A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf, U32* faults);`. After that, compiler tries to call this, but as you know, it's impossible. More unfortunately, there's no function overloading (since `A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf = 0);` is in `class B`.). So the compile error occurs.

To avoid that, renaming your function's name is the best (the easier code is, the better code is). However, if you can't do, use `using`.

```
class D2 : public B
{
    using B::Check_Memory;
    A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf, U32* faults);
}
```

In that case, `A_type* Check_Memory(const LeafInterface* leaf, U32* faults);` doesn't hide `B::Check_Memory`, so the resolving function overloading will be started.